# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.3: not found

Tags: scala, sbt

I am getting the below error on compiling my Twitter streamin Scala program, can some one please suggest to resolve this issue.

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.3 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.2.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.5.1 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/home/muralee1857/scala/workspace/Tutorial/}default-109f4d/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1: not found
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[error] Total time: 28 s, completed 21 Jun, 2017 2:07:50 AM
muralee1857@muralee1857-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:~/scala/workspace/Tutorial$ ^C
muralee1857@muralee1857-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:~/scala/workspace/Tutorial$
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Add more log where all tried resolvers are listed

Comment: I have upgraded SBT verstion to latest 0.13 version and i removed everything from plugins.sbt then it got compiles successfully. I am using SBT package to complie and build my Spark project, when i am checking Spark project jar, it is containing only META-INF folder with MANIFEST.MF file.   and my project in eclipse still showing errors. I am new to Scala and Spark, i am little bit confusing with this execution flow.

Comment: My issue got resolved, i am getting above error because of incompatibility of jars with scala, i have changed my scala compiler version to 2.10, after above issue got resolved, Thank you.

Comment: Still i have many doubts on sbt working. so can someone please explain how SBT is picking jars and how it is compatible to maven. why it is internally using maven and ivy.